# How to Convert a string to the name of an Object

Tags: actionscript-2

I am trying to access the "ID's" of the Object data but for the compiler does not like that...
what is the right way to do this.

```
var objectName:Object = {ID:2, IDName:"this_is_string"};

var target:string="objectName";

trace(target.IDName");  // does not work...
trace("target.ID");
```

any helps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What does "the compiler does not like that" mean? Does it say "Uck! Icky!"? Does it give an error message? If so, what does the message say? The better your question, the better chance you have of getting it answered quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
trace( [target].IDName );
```

Answer (score 0):

That works:

```
trace (eval(target).IDName)
```